# iPhone ScrollView zoom problems

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm new to iPhone dev and Obj-C and I have several problems with ScrollView/ImageView while getting close to deadline. I used IB to create interface so I access most parameters via builder.

1) I was using touch events (begin/moved/ended) on imageView to switch images. When I put ImageView to ScrollView the old gestures stopped working and I can only zoom. If scrollView of both have focus I can't use my gestures even when zoomed out. How can I use both?

2) How do I zoom only image part of view? Unfortunately I also see background area around :/ What's worse - after rotating the view keeps it's old dimensions and I have even more black areas around image. For some reason image is in top-left corner.

Code snippets I found doesn't really help me much in this case. I have various images of different sizes in imageView to switch and zoom in/out.

---

EDIT: Ok, a little different. How do I override scrollview touch mode so that when image is zoomed out (to screen size) "normal" gestures would work. Currenly I have either scroll view scrolling or gestures, can't use both. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by dynamically changing imageview to imagesize and switching like:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    if (scrollView.zoomScale==1.0) {
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Not the best solution but works good enough.